# Liferay LAR import

Tags: liferay, weblogic

My LAR import has been frozen for some time and I can't seem to get rid of it.

[image: Been in progress forever]

Any idea how to eliminate it?

-Liferay 6.2

-Weblogic 12c server

Comment: I havent worked with Liferay 6.2 much, but as a last option you can remove backgroup process which got stucked from database. Related database table name is "backgroundtask"

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, however I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. Have you done it before?

Comment: In database schema, see table backgroundtask and remove entry related to your process(lar import process)